# Flutter cant get ontap function to change boolian list

Tags: flutter

Guys ive been trying to get each button to change the bool list and the containers to get visible when the list goes true for a certain index with big failure.The problem is that for some reason my gesture buttons dont want to change the boolian list but have no problem changing any other integer lists.

I ve been trying to get that simple thing working for a couple days and any help is good.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class FilterRow extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FilterRow({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  _FilterRowState createState() => _FilterRowState();
}

class _FilterRowState extends State<FilterRow> {
  int _filterIndex = 0;
  List<bool> list = [
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
  ];

  List<IconData> _filter = [FontAwesomeIcons.filter];
  List<IconData> _filtericons = [
    FontAwesomeIcons.clock,
    FontAwesomeIcons.moneyBill,
    FontAwesomeIcons.globe,
  ];
  List<IconData> _uppericons = [
    FontAwesomeIcons.cog,
    FontAwesomeIcons.bookmark,
    FontAwesomeIcons.user,
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
          width: 100.0,
          child: Container(
            height: 270.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 15,
            ),
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  GestureDetector(
                    behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        list[0] = false;
                        list[1] = true;
                        list[2] = false;
                        list[3] = false;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 60.0,
                      width: 60.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                      child: Icon(_filtericons[0],
                          size: 25.0, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                    ),
                  ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ]),
          )),
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Visibility(
                visible: false
                    ? list = [
                        false,
                        true,
                        false,
                        false,
                      ]
                    : true,
                child: Container(
                  height: 270.0,
                  width: 320.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                )),
            Visibility(
                visible: false,
                child: Container(
                  height: 270.0,
                  width: 320.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                )),
            Visibility(
                visible: false,
                child: Container(
                  height: 270.0,
                  width: 320.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see you're using `list` anywhere except to set values. Why don't you paste only relevant code?

Comment: Just cleaned the code, I actually do use the list to change values too inside the ontap function of my GestureDetectors.

Answer (score 1):

Put the List variable inside of the Widget function.

```
Widget build(Context context) {

 List<bool> list = [
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
  ];

return // your code

}
```

Comment: I did and still same think except that on my visibility widget my `visible: false
  ? list = [ false, true, false,false,  ] : true, ` is marked as dead code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by removing the @override